Issue with SAML2 in Spring Security 6: InResponseTo Attribute Error When Using Multiple Tab
I am encountering an issue while implementing SAML2 (with a Spring Security provider) in a Spring Security 6 application. The problem arises when using multiple tabs in the same browser.
Here is the sequence of events that leads to the issue:

Open two tabs in the same browser
In tab 1, navigate to the URL that requires authentication: he application redirects to the login page
In tab 2, navigate to the same URL: This also redirects to the login page
Complete the login process in tab 2 -> Authentication is successful.
Switch back to tab 1, which now displays the following error: The response contained an InResponseTo attribute [*****************] but no saved authentication request was found

After some research, I found a solution that bypasses the InResponseTo attribute validation in Spring Security. Here is the relevant configuration:
   @Bean
    public OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider openSaml4AuthenticationProvider() {
        OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider provider = new OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider();

        provider.setResponseValidator(token -> {
            Saml2ResponseValidatorResult result = OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider
                    .createDefaultResponseValidator()
                    .convert(token);
            if (result == null) {
                throw new CustomRuntimeException("Saml2ResponseValidator returned null");
            }

            if (!result.hasErrors()) {
                return result;
            }

            Saml2ResponseValidatorResult newResult = Saml2ResponseValidatorResult.success();
            result.getErrors().forEach(error -> {
                if (!error.getErrorCode().equals(Saml2ErrorCodes.INVALID_IN_RESPONSE_TO)) {
                    newResult.concat(error);
                }
            });
            return newResult;
        });

        provider.setAssertionElementsDecrypter(token -> {
            if (token.getAssertion().getSubject() != null && token.getAssertion().getSubject().getSubjectConfirmations() != null) {
                token.getAssertion().getSubject().getSubjectConfirmations().forEach(subjectConfirmation -> {
                    if (subjectConfirmation.getSubjectConfirmationData() != null) {
                        subjectConfirmation.getSubjectConfirmationData().setInResponseTo(null);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        return provider;
    }

This approach effectively resolves the issue. However, I am concerned about its security implications, as bypassing the InResponseTo attribute validation might introduce vulnerabilities, such as replay attacks.
Questions:
Are there alternative, more secure ways to handle this issue without bypassing the InResponseTo validation?
Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.
